# Finding the original filename when extracting gzip files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip

Quite a while ago a YouTuber posted a puzzle while back and asked his community to solve it. I have already solved this puzzle, but I remembered a part of it that i had always wanted to automate a script for in python. It's basically a file that has been randomly archived 10000+ times. Someone wrote a script that randomly archives the a file over and over with different archiving methods. (.zip, .rar, .jar, .tar. tar.gz, .gz, and .7z) I have been able to extract all of these file types flawlessly except the .gz files. The tar.gz files extract just fine with the `tarfile` module, but the plain .gz files are apparently impossible for it to extract. I can manage to successfully decompress the file, but all that gives me is the raw byte data.

So here is what I am trying to do:

**I need to extract the contents of a plain .gz file (not tar.gz) in python as if I were opening seven zip and extracting with their GUI.**

Some things to mention:

1. The .gz files open just fine in seven zip. I can view the contents and extract them as if they are a normal .zip file.
2. I need the original file name of the archived item. I managed to extract a .zip from one of the .gz files but it only worked if I did this:

   ```
    from gzip import open as gzopen
    with gzopen(file_name, 'rb') as f_in:
        with open('file.zip', 'wb') as f_out:
           copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
   ```

   The problem with this is that it will always extract the .gz as file.zip, even if the actual file that was archived is a .7z or .rar. I need it to correctly identify the extension type and name it appropriately.

Comment: Huh? Why would you name the output file with any extension at all, other than whatever is left after taking `.gz` off the end of the original filename? No reasonable person will ever gzip a zip file, so putting on a `.zip` extension makes no sense.

Comment: ...that is, if a file is `foo.txt.gz`, your output should be just named `foo.txt`; if it's `bar.doc.gz`, the output should be `bar.doc`, etc. The *whole point* of something that's a compressor but not an archiver is that it contains only exactly one file; if it's named correctly (by convention), then that file should just have the compressor extension stripped.

Comment: ...if you have output with names that don't line up with their types, handle them the exact same way you'd handle a file named `foo` with no extension at all. (The conventional way to do that involves libmagic, the library that backs the `file` command on UNIX; that's imperfect in several ways, but a full discussion is out-of-scope here).

Comment: The problem is that there are some instances where the file is just named `file.gz`.

Comment: ...btw, one common case by way you would get a gzip'd zip file is if someone compressed a `docx`, `xlsx`, etc.; as they're all also in zip format, any recent Microsoft Office file can also be parsed as a zip file. (This also makes recompressing them with gzip pretty silly, since they're already compressed).

Comment: right, but that puts you in the same place you would be if you just had something called `file`, and the same fixes apply. There's nothing about the problem, or its solutions, that are in any way unique to gzip (unless the gzip header with the original filename is filled in, but as that's an optional field, I wouldn't bet on it; even if it exists in some of your data, if you use it, you need to write code that works correctly when it doesn't exist to have a robust solution).

Comment: ...so, once again, libmagic is your friend -- and Google indicates that you have lots of choices in terms of Python bindings available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GZIP algorithm doesn't compress *files*, it compresses a *stream* of bytes.  Of course, files can be seen as stream of bytes as well but files have a lot of other attributes (names, owners, dates, permissions, etc.).  A raw stream of bytes lacks all of these.

So, if `gzip` as an executable compresses a file, it simply compresses the file's contents and leaves everything else (owner, dates, etc.) intact.  Except for the name:  It appends a `.gz` suffix.

So, if you want to know the original name of the file, just strip the `.gz` suffix, that's it.

Of course, `gzip` can also be used to compress other streams, e.g. user input, or the output of a command.  If it does not have a file at hand, it will direct the compressed stream of bytes to stdout from where it can be redirected into some file again.  And this file can have the suffix `.gz` again (and often has).  So, a file whose name ends in `.gz` isn't necessarily the compressed version of a file of this name without the `.gz` suffix.

Some combinations of suffixes are often abbreviated, e.g. `.tar.gz` is often named `.tgz`.

Comment: `gzip` actually stores the file name: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71728455/1501222