# How to get the original file name from a .gz archive from php

Tags: php, gzip

I'm trying to recover the original file name in a gz archive with php.

I tried with gzip and gzfile and I just manage to decompress it but not to recover the original name. The name that I recover is just the name of the archive without the gz

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't. Gzip is a stream compression algorithm and has no concept of files or filenames. If you want file metadata you need to use an actual archive format like TAR or ZIP that _do_ care about such things.

Comment: Put another way: the original filename is stored in the gzip's filename, before the ".gz" extension. That arguably IS the metadata, which it uses to establish the target filename when extracting, unless overridden. If you've changed the filename, you've essentially changed that metadata.

Comment: Thanks for your answers how does the ubuntu archive manager get this info?  Because when I open a renamed gz in ubuntu I have the original name that is displayed ?

Answer (score 1):

The comments are simply wrong. Gzip **can** store filename metadata. See [section 2.3 Member Format in RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952).

And luckily the `gzip` command line tool does store that information by default. You can restore the original file name with the `--name` option:

```sh
echo foo > bar
gzip bar
mv bar.gz asdf.gz
ls -lA
# -rwx------ 1 user group 28 Apr  3 19:41 asdf.gz
gzip --decompress --keep --name asdf.gz
ls -lA
# -rwx------ 1 user group 28 Apr  3 19:41 asdf.gz
# -rwx------ 1 user group  4 Apr  3 19:41 bar
```

You can get the original name also by combining `--name` with `--list`:

```sh
gzip --name --list asdf.gz
```

Output:

```
compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
        28                   4 -50.0% bar
```